# Как добраться до содержащего ContextMenu элемента WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

Подскажите как получить ссылку в обработчике события (например Click) ContextMenu  на тот элемент интерфейса к которому ContextMenu привязан. Пример разметки`

```
<TextBlock Text="123">
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Копировать" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

В обработчике события хочу получить, например,  TextBlock.Text.

```
private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //TextBlock tbl = (TextBlock) SOMETHING???;
    //MessageBox.Show(tbl.Text);
}
```

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но больше интересно зачем это может понадобиться. Просто используйте MVVM, у вас к пункту меню будет привязана команда и нам остается только передать в нее правильный параметр. Расскажите что вы делаете и я (или кто-то еще) напишу как это сделать *правильно*.

Comment: В общем виде есть свойство `Parent`: `(sender as FrameworkElement)?.Parent`

Comment: @AlexKrass, не выйдет, у Popup Parent равен null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
var target = (TextBlock)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
MessageBox.Show(target.Text);
```

---

Но правильнее будет определить команду копирования, и определить её обработчик.

```
<TextBlock Text="123">
    <TextBlock.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" CanExecute="OnCanCopy" Executed="OnCopy"/>
    </TextBlock.CommandBindings>
    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cm">
            <MenuItem Command="Copy"
                      CommandTarget="{Binding Path=Parent.PlacementTarget,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
</TextBlock>
```

Code-behind:

```
void OnCanCopy(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}

void OnCopy(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBlock)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
}
```

(Это даёт то преимущество, что команда копирования обрабатывается не только при вызове контекстного меню.)

К сожалению, контекстное меню находится в другом визуальном дереве, поэтому нам пришлось вручную «подвязать» `CommandTarget`. Трюк с `Focus` [отсюда](https://www.wpftutorial.net/RoutedCommandsInContextMenu.html) у меня не сработал, судя по всему потому, что в тестовом примере не было элементов, которые могли получить фокус.

Comment: Спасибо. За оба варианта. Собственно мне нужно было свойство ContextMenu.PlacementTarget.